# Require Export changes requirements in every file

Tags: module, coq, coqide, logical-foundations

I'm new to Coq, and currently going through the Software Foundations series of tutorials.

However, I keep finding myself struggling with getting the `Require Export` part working on the first try, every file seemingly requiring a new strategy to work. This time, however, I am stuck entirely.

In one file (Lists.v) I am able to simply write
`From LF Require Export Induction.`, and have it work just fine.

In the very next one (Poly.v), I can't load the Lists module at all,

```
From LF Require Export Lists. 
(* ==> Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix
<> and prefix LF. *)
```

Unless I first add the load path to the current folder:

```
Add LoadPath "~/Documents/code/coq/".
From LF Require Export Lists. (* Works perfectly! *)
```

However, next chapter in, and nothing seems to be working.

Here's what I've tried:

```
From LF Require Export Poly.
(* ==> Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix
<> and prefix LF. *)
```

---

```
Add LoadPath "~/Documents/code/coq/".
From LF Require Export Poly.
(* ==> The file /Users/coffee/Documents/code/coq/LF/Poly.vo contains library Poly
and not library LF.Poly *)
```

---

```
Add LoadPath "~/Documents/code/coq/LF/".
From LF Require Export Poly.
(* ==> Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix
<> and prefix LF. *)
```

---

```
Add LoadPath "~/Documents/code/coq/LF/".
Require Export Poly.
(* ==> Cannot load LF.Basics: no physical path bound to LF *)
```

Safe to say: I'm at a loss here, I have no idea what I'm doing or why it's not working.
It worked before, and nothing I can find online seems to give any good answers.

My _CoqProject file contains `-Q . LF`

I'm experiencing this issue both on Windows and Mac.

And I'm using the latest version of CoqIDE.

Comment: Apparently, you don't compile and load the files consistently, i.e. taking the `-Q . LF` of the `_CoqProject` into account. Could you explain how you compile the files? And could you show what `Print LoadPath` outputs?

Comment: @eponier this is the output of print loadpath: https://pastebin.com/ZAQa8QL0

And I compile each file individually before importing it in the exact same way across the board

Comment: Thank you for the details. But what I meant was: do you use `make` or the menu button of CoqIDE to compile?

Comment: Anyways, you shouldn't need to use `Add LoadPath`. The `_CoqProject` should be sufficient.

Comment: I use the menu button, make doesn't work.

And I know I shouldn't use Add Loadpath, but as I stated it doesn't work in one of the files without it

Comment: Can you build via the command line instead? `cd ~/.../LF` and `coqc -Q . LF Poly.v`. Since coqide doesn't seem to be picking up `_CoqProject`, but you can still at least tell it where to find the files, then being able to build the files with the right options should let you move forward. Also, `Add LoadPath "~/.../LF" as LF.` would be the equivalent of `-Q . LF`, to avoid the mismatch between how things are compiled and how they are looked up by coqide.

Comment: It compiles fine in the console without the explicit loadpath, but the IDE refuses to parse the `Require Export` line

Comment: Closing the IDE and opening it again seems to magically have resolved the issue

Comment: When you create a new file, CoqIDE cannot use its location to find the associated `_CoqProject` until it is saved. And even when it's saved, it does not take it into account immediately. You have to close the tab and reopen the file to have everything work.

Comment: When you use the menu button, it shows the command that it actually uses to compile, so you can check that the correct option is passed to `coqc`. In particular, `-Q . LF`.